# What is the validity period of Android In-app billing cache hold by Google Play?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm using the In-App billing v3 in my Android app for subscriptions.
Now I'm testing it in real scenario, I bought a month subscription a month ago and now, after a month I received an email of renewal charge.
It's a couple of hours (about 7) but the method `getPurchases()` is still returning the information about the old purchase bought a month ago.

I readed an information about [local caching](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#caching) of purchases data, but I didn't find an information **how long is the cache valid**?

I understand that device can be offline, so the cache cannot be updated, so let's assume that my device is constantly connected to Internet.

Comment: Sadly, i won't be able to invalidate it except for "clear cache" in Google Play application settings. Before that in-app returned to me the value almost 3 or 4 months old 8(

Comment: So it means that I cannout use the getPurchases() for checking subscription renewal, right?